# Is there any Evernote alternative with offline availability support?

Tags: evernote, ios

Evernote has recently closed its offline notebook support and because of limited availability of wi-fi access in my workplace, I'm planning to switch to another cloud note taking tool. The main reason I do not use iOS's builtin note taking app, is its lack of support for folders (This problem also exists for Pages).

Do you know any alternatives with support of making folders for documents and offline support?

Comment: http://www.alternativeto.net/software/evernote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The main reason I do not use iOS's builtin note taking app, is its
>   lack of support for folders

On notes in iOS 9 and OS X 10.11 or later, you can [organize notes in folders](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph23057?locale=en_US).

I use it as an Evernote alternative, and think it's much better for it's simplicity, offline support and sync between devices. I've never found anything else that can match it's usability.

Answer (score 2):

There are many alternatives, though perhaps none with the richness of Evernote.

BTW, I think that offline support is still available. It was available for favourites on the standard login but for everything if you sign up for Premium - has that changed?

One alternative is Microsoft OneNote. You can have free OneNote notebooks by signing up to live.com, the OneNote app for iOS works OK but has pretty harsh restrictions at present. There are, however, a couple of (paid) alternative apps. This would be of most use if you have a version of MS Office that includes OneNote on the desktop.

Alternatively, something like TrunkNotes may be useful. This is like a WIKI and you can sync with Dropbox.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I was looking for offline support on a free plan.

Comment: No problem - have you tried using Favorites - does that still work?

Answer (score 0):

Offline note support is available for iOS and Android if you are a Premium user. http://evernote.com/premium/